# How to use wildcards in path in gradle-groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a project which builds temporary folders named 'target' during the gradle build.
I need to delete them in gradle clean.
I added the following in `build.gradle` and tried running `gradle clean` didn't work for me.

```
clean {
    delete("${projectDir}/**/target")
}
```

If `**` is replaced with a path it works.
Since these folders are created in multiple locations looking for a wildcard approach.

Is there any way of doing this?

**Edit:**
The compiled `target` folders are created on different levels. Currently, I clean them as follows. ( Need to add more entries when adding new test cases with resources). Looking for a shorthand method.

```
clean{
delete("${projectDir}/src/test/resources/federationGateway/subgraphServices/subgraphService1/target")
delete("${projectDir}/src/test/resources/federationGateway/target")
}
```

Comment: quick q... why are you creating directories in `src/test` as part of the build? Could you change this to write instead to `build/generated/resources/federationGateway`, and add `build/generated` to the test source-set?

Comment: It's not intentional. I'm using an API to compile the projects which are in test resources for the test cases. (Projects are in `Ballerina` language and using `JBallerinaBackend` APIs ).